# how can i change the radio button via next prev

Tags: jquery

I have my slick slider and want to know how can i change the radio buttons via next and prev buttons, i'm not good at js or jquery, if you can help me i would be more than happy :(

```
            <section class="center slider">
            <div class="type">
            <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="1" checked /><img src="./images/1.png"></label>
            </div>
            <div  class="type">
            <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="2" /><img src="./images/2.png"></label>
            </div>
            <div  class="type">
            <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="3" /><img src="./images/3.png"></label>
            </div>
            <div  class="type">
            <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="4" /><img src="./images/4.png"></label>
            </div>
            <div  class="type">
            <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="5" /><img src="./images/5.png"></label>
            </div>
            <div  class="type">
            <label> <input type="radio" name="type" value="6"/><img src="./images/6.png"></label>
            </div>
            <div  class="type">
            <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="7" /><img src="./images/7.png"></label>
            </div>
        </section>

        <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">Previous</button>

        <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">Next</button>
```

i tried to use some js:

```
<button type="button" onclick="dayNavigation('prev');"data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">Next</button>

<button type="button" onclick="dayNavigation('next');" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">Previous</button>

dayNavigation = function (direction) {
    var all = $('.slider input:radio');
    var current = $('.slider input:radio:checked');
    var index;
    if (direction == 'slick-prev') {
        index = all.index(current) - 1;       
    } else {
        index = all.index(current) + 1;        
    }

    if(index >= all.size()) index = 0;
    all.eq(index).click();
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Can you please add the Css code too. and add the library you have used in this model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eq()` function from JQuery combined with the `.prop()` function to achieve this.

Here's the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jPfXS/111/

```
<button type="button" onclick="dayNavigation('prev');"data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">Next</button>

<button type="button" onclick="dayNavigation('next');" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">Previous</button>

var index = 0;
dayNavigation = function (direction) {
    var curr = $('.slider input[name="type"]:checked');
    console.log(curr);
    if(direction == 'next'){
        if(index > 0){
            $('input[name="type"]').eq(index-1).prop("checked", true);
            curr.prop("checked", false);
            index--;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(index < $('input[name="type"]').length - 1){
            $('input[name="type"]').eq(index+1).prop("checked", true);
            curr.prop("checked", false);
            index++;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I edited the answer and the fiddle for it to work. I also added a support if you're on the first/last input.

Comment: just a little problem, my button is in a .js file, how can i make the 'prev' 'next' to work? because with 'prev' is not working:  ex from js file: prevArrow: '<button type="button" onclick="dayNavigation("prev"); class="slick-prev">Previous</button>',

Comment: The `dayNavigation` function only tests if the parameters is `'next'`. otherwise it considers that the button pressed is by default `'prev'`